# Google Mail Filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In our office we have automated emails that are being sent to all of our inboxes to confirm orders made and to confirm text messages sent out to our users.

We want a filter that automatically mark those emails as read or that puts the emails away in another inbox. But if a customer answers to an automated email, we want to show the email in inbox again (unread) instead of the other inbox we sent the email to with our filters.

Is this possible? Or should we look into another solution?